# App crashes when using fragments with a GoogleMap

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, google-maps-android-api-2, android-fragmentactivity

My app crashes when I use fragments and its obviously related to the `GoogleMap` inside one of the fragments.

I already changed the map fragment from `MapFragment` to `SupportMapFragment` but it didnt help.

this is the Main page where all the fragments are (the `FragmentActivity`):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;

public class Fragments extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragments);

        MainActivity fragment = new MainActivity();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_place, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public void onSelectFragment(View view) {

        Fragment newFragment;

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.add)) {
            newFragment = new Add();
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.map)) {
            newFragment = new MainActivity();
        } else {
            newFragment = new MainActivity();
        }

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

the logcat:

```
09-30 15:03:19.257: W/dalvikvm(12895): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ed5300)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:284)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at com.example.free.MainActivity.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:122)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5018)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
09-30 15:03:19.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and the fragment is kinda large so Ive pasted it on pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/G9MekK1Z

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: have you referenced google play services library project in your android map project

Comment: @Raghunandan yes.There is `google play services` under `Referenced libraries`.

Comment: refer my updated answer

Comment: @NirPes how did you refer your library project. I suspect you have not done that properly and can you post your manifest file and xml layout file

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use the SupportMapFragment:  http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html

Here's a good tutorial:
http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-supportmapfragment-example/

Comment: the perrmission you have provided is for Google Maps API V1 and is not used in API V2.

Comment: Ah - thanks for the heads up.  I had forgotten the project I was referencing was done in v1. Updating my answer.  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is include a Google Play Services library to your project. Google has very good instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html):

Please visit [code.google.com](http://code.google.com) and get your ApiKey.

create a project there->go to services->Activate the Google Maps Android API v2. Then Create Key for your application.

Add the following permissions to your manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.anchit.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

use

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your_apikey" />
```

also add inside your application tag

```
<permission
        android:name="com.anchit.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
```

Please use following in your code:

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
```

Comment: op has not metioned what api he is using so why do you need to change `SupportMapFragment` to `MapFragment`?. also docs does not mention the permission you have in your post `<permission
        android:name="com.anchit.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />`. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: No. My manifast is ok and I need `SupportMapFragment` for it to work within a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this blog post I wrote on how to integrate Google Map API V2 in your application, it might just get you a solution for your problem:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Answer (score 0):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
}
```

use this instead of oncreate()